# MySql InnoDB possible performance issues

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, query-optimization

I'm newb with Databases, so what i have:

- One table ~75GB. (InnoDB)
- 10GB of indexes in it.
- high traffic

After few cheap select queries I have insert query and other select's against this huge table.

Question: With each inserting there will be reindexing and it may lock the table/or row or what ? how it will affect with high traffic, when multiple request at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are *incrementally* updated.  There is no need to think about this process; it happens in the 'background'.  The indexes are always up-to-date; that is, a `SELECT` will be able to find a freshly-inserted row as easily as an old row.

If you get more than, say, 100 `INSERTs` per second, let's look into the details.  (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`, actual `INSERT`, etc)

Meanwhile, a thousand point-queries should be no problem.  (That is `SELECT` of a single row that is indexed.)

High traffic...  "Cheap queries" are often so fast that there are rarely two running simultaneously.  Even a thousand queries per second might rarely have more than a few running at the same time.  Long-running queries is another thing.

A few dozen *actively* running connections is 'heavy' traffic.  At that point, let's look at the longest-running queries and see if we can speed them up.

Depending on RAM size and `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, and depending on the access patterns, your large table may *or may not* be I/O bound.  UUID/GUID indexes are notorious for leading to I/O sluggishness.  A "log" or "news", where you are mostly looking at "recent" rows will have a "locality of reference" that leads to very efficient caching - hence table size versus RAM does not matter.